# props.data.map does not work in my component

Tags: reactjs, react-props, array.prototype.map

I am learning react and I am also new to JS, can someone please tell me why does the .map function in one component work, but doesn't work in another component?

Map works well in this component

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from './card';
import '../memoryGameStyle/cardList.css';

const CardList =(props)=>{
    const card=props.cards.map((c,i)=>(
        <Card
            key={i}
            card={c}
            cards={props}
        />
    ))
    return(
        <div className='card-list'>
            {card}
        </div>
    )
}

export default CardList;
```

but it does not work in this component

```
import React from 'react';
import '../memoryGameStyle/card.css';

class Card extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        const {hidden,show,id,r,g,b}=this.props.card
        this.state={...}
        const style='';
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(){...}

    onClick=()=>{
        const {id}=this.props.card
        this.setState({hidden:false})
        this.setState({show:true})
        const cards=this.props.cards.map((card,i)=>{
            console.log(card)
        })
    }
render(){...}
```

I have this error every time

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending incorrect data to the `Card` component.

Change

```
<Card
  key={i}
  card={c}
  cards={props}
/>
```

to

```
<Card
  key={i}
  card={c}
  cards={props.cards}
/>
```

Hope, you figured out the mistake.

Comment: oh I see it now, thank you, 8 more minutes and I can accept your answer

Comment: Cool, sounds great!